# showing argument in QMessageBox->setText

Tags: qt, qlineedit, qmessagebox

I have `QMessageBox` defined as

```
m_setting2 = new QMessageBox();
m_setting2->setWindowTitle("NOTE");
m_setting2->setText("RESETTING PREFERENTIAL VALUE TO ");
m_setting2->show();
```

where `m_setting2` is my `QMessageBox*`.

Now after `VALUE TO` in `setText` I want to add an argument which is an integer taken from `QLineEdit`. This integer is stored in `valuee`.

So how can i print that integer after `VALUE TO`.

Somewhere I saw that it should be something like `QString.("%1").arg(valuee)` but it's not working.

Please help me out and thanks for any type of concern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int value = 5;
QString text = QString("RESETTING PREFERENTIAL VALUE TO %1").arg(value);
m_setting2->setText(text);
```